# Trouble connecting to localdb via SQLCMD in PowerShell - what is server instance name?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sqlcmd, localdb

SQL Server newbie here - I'm trying to access the localdb\MSSQLLocalDB server on my computer through PowerShell with the SQLCMD utility. I'm using PowerShell v5, .NET v5.0, and The server name is `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` when I connect to it in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014.

`PS C:\> sqlcmd -S localdb\MSSQLLocalDB` and `PS C:\> sqlcmd -S .\localdb\MSSQLLocalDB` result in this error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : SQL Server
>   Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified
>   [xFFFFFFFF].

I queried the server name in Management Studio with `SELECT @@ServerName` and used that after the `-S` in the above command and got the same error.

`PS C:\> sqlcmd -S localdb` gives this error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Named Pipes
>   Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]

Other notes: I'm able to connect to the server and work with a database named *testdb01* in a C# console app using `System.Data.SqlClient` with this connection string:

```
"Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=testdb01;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

Any ideas on where to start or how to approach this?

Answer (score 5):

Passing arguments from PowerShell to EXEs can be tricky. I think you need to escape the parens either with single quotes, which means the content is a static literal string, or the backtick escape character:

```
sqlcmd -S '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB' -Q "Select @@servername"

sqlcmd -S `(localdb`)\MSSQLLocalDB -Q "Select @@servername"
```

or even using a variable:

```
PS H:\> $myserver = '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB'

PS H:\> sqlcmd -S $myserver -Q "Select @@servername"
```

Also, if you are using sqlcmd, perhaps look at Invoke-Sqlcmd which is more native to PowerShell:

```
PS SQLSERVER:\> Invoke-Sqlcmd -Server $myserver -Query "Select @@servername"
```

Comment: Using `Invoke-Sqlcmd` solved my connection-issue. Thanks!