# Cannot connect to LocalDB via sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, database, powershell, sqlcmd

I am currently learning SQL Server and am having problems connecting to my local database using `sqlcmd`.

When I type in the following into Powershell:

```
sqlcmd -S "(localdb)\mssqllocaldb"
```

I get the following error message:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : SQL Server Network Interfaces: The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
>   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

I can connect to the local database if I use SQL Server Management Studio. I can also connect to the local database if I use the instance name pipe.

I have a clean install of Windows 10 x64, Visual Studio Community, and SQL Server Management Studio 2016.

Comment: Is `(localdb)` your hostname and `mssqllocaldb` the name of your database instance? Did you [enable the TCP protocol](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231672%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)? [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-ch/library/ms188247.aspx).

Comment: Using `Invoke-Sqlcmd` solved this issue for me. Se the suggestion in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457048/trouble-connecting-to-localdb-via-sqlcmd-in-powershell-what-is-server-instance

Comment: having the same issue, still no answer

Comment: @IliaG there was a driver bug. check my answer for links to the new driver download

Comment: @CarrieKendall thanks, I'll check it out, though the need has since long passed :)

Answer (score 16):

There was a [driver bug](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32903026-odbc-driver-13-for-sql-server-cannot-connect-to-lo) in ODBC Drive 13. Installing ODBC Driver 13.1 update will fix this.

You can [download the driver here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53339).

Afterwards, you should be able to use in cmd or powershell:

```
sqlcmd -S "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" -i C:\path\to\file.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

I just got this error and [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1201271/Devs-User-Guide-To-SqlLocalDb-Sql-Express) solved the problem for me.  Start reading from where it says "Visual Studio 2017 & Pathing".

> The error message actually occurs because my path variable is pointing to an older version of the sqlcmd tool....  The one that works for all of my SQL Express engines is at:
>
> > C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\

Using the sqlcmd in that directory worked for me.

Comment: This was what was wrong with my setup, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
sqlcmd -S ".\mssqllocaldb"
```

or

```
sqlcmd -S ".\mssqllocaldb -uYOUR_User -pYOUR_PASSWORD"
```

Comment: And also make sure the service is started